# $(f_ng_n)$ that does not converge uniformly to $fg$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that the sequences $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ converge uniformly to respective functions $f$ and $g$ on some domain $S$. Can someone provide me with a counterexample (preferably with proof) of sequences $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ converge uniformly to $f$ and $g$ on $S$ but $(f_ng_n)$ does NOT converge uniformly to $fg$ on $S$.

Comment: Already answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256323/does-f-ng-n-to-fg-uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f_n,g_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that send $x$ to $x+\frac{1}{n}$. Clearly $f_n,g_n$ converge uniformly to $f(x)=x$, but $f_ng_n$ does not converge uniformly to $x^2$.